# vue get all images within component that are not part of a child component

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue mixin to inline svg images:

```
Vue.mixin({
    mounted: function () {
        for (let image of document.images as any) {
            if (!image.src.endsWith('.svg') || (!image.classList.contains('svg') && !image.parentNode.classList.contains('svg'))) continue
            inlineSvg(image)
        }
    }
})
```

Unfortunately the function gets called on all images when a component mounts instead of only its own images.

What can I replace `document.images` with to only get the images within the component?  (Not including images of child components since they should be handled during their own mounted event)

Comment: Use a `ref` on the parent container and loop it's children